# Finding departments that have never handled a certain item

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables

```
dept:
dept_name
...

sale:
sale_num
sale_qty
item_name
dept_name
```

I want to find the departments that have never handled the most popular item denoted by max(sum(sqty))

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: *I want to find the departments that have never handled the most popular item denoted by max(sum(sqty))* What if a lot of items have the same maximal value?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Akina, i think in such case it should consider all the max items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do this in two steps

1. first determine popular item using a subquery
2. then write sql to not to pick data from that subquery.

To get popular items -

```
select item_name,qty from (
select item_name, qty , rank() over (order by qty desc ) rn from (
select item_name, sum(qty ) qty  from sale group by item_name) rs) where rn = 1
```

And then you can write a simple `not in ()` to fetch desired departments.
Full SQL should look like this -

```
select distinct d.* from dept d, sales s 
where d.dept_name = s.dept_name and 
s.item_name not in (
select item_name from (
select item_name, qty , rank() over (order by qty desc ) rn from (
select item_name, sum(qty ) qty  from sale group by item_name) rs)rs2 where rs2.rn = 1
)
```

Pls note, i used item_name as identifier and name can cause issue sometimes(i prefer item id). I tested on Oracle so pls test on your mysql before implementing it.

Comment: This worked really well, appreciate it!!